# PHP Issues With Switching Cases and $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Hey so I am making a quick PHP program that allows simple mathematical computations. And instead of having the output go to different pages from the _POST, I want them all to go to the same page.
So I tried using a function that would see the _POST data and differentiate the input  and run different functions based upon the input.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

```
<h1>Add:</h1>
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    #1: <input type="text" name="a1"><br>
    #2: <input type="text" name="a2"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
    <input type="submit" name="addsubmit">
    </form>
<hr />
<h1>Subtract:</h1>
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    #1: <input type="text" name="s1"><br>
    #2: <input type="text" name="s2"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subtract">
    <input type="submit" name="subsubmit">
    </form>
<hr />
<h1>Multiply:</h1>
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    #1: <input type="text" name="m1"><br>
    #2: <input type="text" name="m2"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="multiply">
    <input type="submit" name="multisubmit">
    </form>
<hr />
<h1>Divide:</h1>
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
    #1: <input type="text" name="d1"><br>
    #2: <input type="text" name="d2"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="divide">
    <input type="submit" name="divsubmit">
    </form>



</body>
```

~~~

```
<?php



$a1 = $_POST["a1"];
$a2 = $_POST["a2"];
$s1 = $_POST["s1"];
$s2 = $_POST["s2"];
$m1 = $_POST["m1"];
$m2 = $_POST["m2"];
$d1 = $_POST["d1"];
$d2  = $_POST["d2"];


function add($num1, $num2){
    echo $num1 + $num2;
}

function subtract($num1, $num2){
    echo $num1 - $num2; 
}

function multiply($num1, $num2){
    echo $num1 * $num2;
}

function divide($num1, $num2){
    echo $num1 / $num2;
}

function operate(){


    switch($_POST['submit']) {
        case 'addsubmit':
            add($a1, $a2);
            break;
        case 'subsubmit':
            subtract($s1, $s2);
            break;
        case 'multisubmit':
            multiply($m1, $m2);
            break;
        case 'divsubmit':
            divide($d1, $d2);
            break;
    }

}



?>
```

```
    <div id="1">
        <h1>Addition:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <h1>Subtraction:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="3">
        <h1>Multiplication:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="4">
        <h1>Division:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
    </div>

    <button> <a href="/workspaces/testgrounds/addition.php">Back to main page</a></button>
</body>
```

~~
Edit1:

[First Errors](http://prntscr.com/94c3ag) ||  [Second Errors](http://prntscr.com/94c3k6) –

Comment: What's not working? what errors do you get?

Comment: 1. You need to actually call the `operate()` function somewhere - currently loading the file wont run any code, just define a bunch of functions. 2. As only 2 POST variables will be set at any one time, the 1st 8 lines of code will generate at least 6 undefined index errors - you should use `isset` to check, and you might as well put the variable initialization within the switch case block

Comment: You're switching on $_POST['submit'], which is not posted in (there is no form element with name "submit").

Comment: @DigitalChris

http://prntscr.com/94c3ag (First errors)

http://prntscr.com/94c3k6 (Second errors same page)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I thought that the value type = submit would be covered by the $_POST['submit']

Comment: @MatthewMariner Do a var_dump of your $_POST so you see what you're getting...

Comment: @EatPeanutButter 

    array (size=4)
      'a1' => string '22' (length=2)
      'a2' => string '22' (length=2)
      'action' => string 'add' (length=3)
      'addsubmit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$a1 = $_POST["a1"];
$a2 = $_POST["a2"];
$s1 = $_POST["s1"];
$s2 = $_POST["s2"];
$m1 = $_POST["m1"];
$m2 = $_POST["m2"];
$d1 = $_POST["d1"];
$d2  = $_POST["d2"];


function add($num1, $num2){
    return $num1 + $num2;
}

function subtract($num1, $num2){
    return $num1 - $num2; 
}

function multiply($num1, $num2){
    return $num1 * $num2;
}

function divide($num1, $num2){
    return $num1 / $num2;
}

 function operate() {

    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'add':
            return add($a1, $a2);
            break;
        case 'subtract':
            return subtract($s1, $s2);
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            return multiply($m1, $m2);
            break;
        case 'divide':
            return divide($d1, $d2);
            break;
    }
}

?>

    <div id="1">
        <h1>Addition:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <h1>Subtraction:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="3">
        <h1>Multiplication:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
        <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="4">
        <h1>Division:</h1>
        Your answer is <?php echo operate(); ?><br />
    </div>

    <button> <a href="/workspaces/testgrounds/addition.php">Back to main page</a></button>
</body>
```

You should add some isset() tests to your variable assignments at the beginning of this, too.

Comment: The action helped but I still have errors, so I moved the variable initialization in the switch case block and that got rid of all the errors but now it won't compute anything.

Oddly.

Comment: If it's inside the operate() function, you have to call that function to make it compute. What errors do you see?

Comment: Concerning the var_dump, it depends on which submit button I press in the original HTML page

Comment: Thanks so much @EatPeanutButter , I tried a very similar solution previously but it didn't work.
The only issue I still have is that when I compute a number for one function, the results page lists the results under all divisions for that same function.